# Patterns in Prefixing with "ver-" and "er-"

Tags: standard-german

It seems that adjectives ending in "-lich" tend often to be prefixed (when possible) by "ver-" [EDIT: when forming verbs from the "er-" and "ver-" prefixes]. Is there a reason for this? Are there other suffixes that tend towards one prefix or the other?

Additionally, I'm not aware of any umlauted-adjective for which there formally exists compounds with both "ver-" and "er-" ("ergänzen," no "vergänzen," etc.). Is there a reason for this, or is this an unfounded recognition?

List of "ver-" prefixes:

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:German_words_prefixed_with_ver-

List of "er-" prefixes:

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:German_words_prefixed_with_er-

Answer (score 2):

Like I already stated on your other question, the form or sound or anything like that has nothing to do with the use of prefixes. There is maybe a correlation however, but the reason lays elsewhere.
So for the difference of *"er-"* and *"ver-"*, it's a bit hard to explain exaclty, but here's another try from my side: The *"er-"* often indicates that something is applied on itself (an internal action), for example:

> erblinden, erheben, erstarren, erröten (or as you asked in your other question, erblöden)

It's not possible "jemanden zu erblinden, jemanden erstarren, jemanden erröten, etc", it's only possible on oneself: "Ich erblinde, er erstarrt, sie erröten, etc..."
*"ver-"* on the other hand doesn't has such a role, for more information read my answers on your other questions. ("be-", "ver-", "zer-")

Comment: aber man kann jemand anderen erschießen, erstechen, erschlagen oder sonstwie ermorden

Answer (score 1):

Quote:

> It seems that adjectives ending in "-lich" tend often to be prefixed (when possible) by "ver-."

This presumption is wrong, as you can easily see by searching for `*lich` at the [DWDS](https://bit.ly/2TAlacT).